# How to make nodejs request https server just like a browser?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

I have an API server which already has a SSL cert from COMODO.

Everything works when I request through jQuery in the browser.

However, the https request in NodeJS always report 
{ [Error: certificate not trusted] code: 'CERT_UNTRUSTED' }

I don't want to create self signed cert.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Could you post a sample request so we can get a feel of how exactly you are making the request.

Comment: I just solved the stupid question by reinstalling my node js on Mac.  What a waste of time!  A https server with COMODO cert don't need any custom CAs at all. :(